# how to hide a complete asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

I want a page to run in the background in my Asp .Net web application. 
That page should not be visible to the user.

The exact use of this page: the user will schedule a mail, that is to be send later. After he scheduled, the page should be hidden.

Can we do it?

Platform version (.NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a service.

However, there are several kludgy ways to do back ground tasks with asp.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/129/Simple-task-Scheduling-using-Global.asax

Answer (score 0):

If the user closes the browser before your scheduled event has occurred, it will never take place.

You really want a backend service that processed queued events.  When the user schedules an email it adds it to the queue and then gets picked up and processed by the backend service.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ is one option for it, or you could build a window's service and the queue manually.

Alternatively you could look into a service bus approach such as http://www.nservicebus.com/ which is backed by MSMQ.